# In Hereditary, how does Annie get into the attic?

Tags: plot-explanation, hereditary

At the end of Hereditary, there's a scene where Annie is banging her head on the attic door, then a few moments with Peter discovering things in the attic, then suddenly Annie appears floating at the attic's ceiling.

But how did she get there in the first place? Did the cult open up the attic door for her in the background? Is this ever explained?

Comment: This is a horror-themed super-natural movie, we cannot really use common sense or physics to explain every scene.

Comment: @YuZhang I know, but often even supernatural elements have rules. For example, in Hereditary, we know Paiman can only enter people when they are at their weakest.

Comment: the head of Annie is part of the ritual .. i think it's a fair assumption to make that the cult let her in when Peter was looking at his picture.

Comment: I provided a possible answer below and by doing so I contradicted with my own comment above. :-}

Answer (score 3):

I think that at this point Peter is already lost, and that Paimon is just viciously playing with the members of the family whose souls or bodies he has been offered.

During those scenes we see Annie's body levitating;  Paimon could probably easily open the attic trap, bumping Annie's head onto it a bit harder maybe, and levitate her into the room.

Answer (score 1):

It is very likely for one of the cultists that opens the attic door for Annie. Please refer to this captured image from the movie.

- It was taken right after Peter escaped into the attic and before Annie gets in.

There are lots of those shadowy cultists inside their house through this movie.

[image]

Disclaimer:

- This image was captured from *Heavy Spoilers* youTube channel, from the video named INSANE Hidden Details in *HEREDITARY That Make It One of The Creepiest Horrors EVER*.